# How to get the PageNavigationType to work through a loop

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

I am trying to collect information from a range in a Google Sheet and create a Form using Google Script. Depending on user input within the form, the user should be guided to a specific page within the form. Pages are created through a loop and I need help to put the right navigationType on the createChoice item  inside the generated multiple choice.

On the Sheet range, say Sheet1 range A1:D10, the data in the first row (A1:D1) contains the Multiple choice titles. Rows A2:D10 are the options. If an option is equal to a range/value in the first row, then if user selects this option he should be able to go to that page within the form. Only rule is that every option in each column should point to next columns, not before, therefore a choice in Column B should not point to Column A and can only point to Columns C or D.

You may find the Google Sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lpvqvmK2zyZHOgqbk9ICCatGclUqatjOJ4wz7D7911M/edit?usp=sharing)

The code below already creates this function, however gets stuck on setGoToPages, for all pages. Any input on what I am not doing right?

```
function TheForm() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Sheet = SS.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var data = Sheet.getRange('A1:D10').getValues();
  
  //  Creating the form
  var form = FormApp.create('Input')
  .setDescription('Some description')
  .setConfirmationMessage('Have a fruity day:)')
  .setAllowResponseEdits(true)
  .setAcceptingResponses(true);
        
  //  adding the Fruits column in first page
  var itemPage1 = form.addListItem()
                  .setTitle('Fruits')
                  .setRequired(true);
  
  var PageNamesValues = [];
  for (var x=data[0].length-1; x>0; x--) {
      var choices = [];
      var choicesPage1 = []
      if (data[0][x] !== '') {
        // Create all other pages
        // My problem is how to set the page names so that I can refer to later!      
        var PageName = form.addPageBreakItem()
        .setTitle(data[0][x]);
        PageNamesValues.push(PageName.getTitle());
        Logger.log(PageName.getTitle());
        Logger.log(PageNamesValues);

        PageName.setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);
        
        var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
        .setTitle(data[0][x])
        .showOtherOption(false)
        .setRequired(true);
        
        Logger.log('PageName is "'+PageName+'"');
        for (var z=1; z<data.length; z++) {  
          if (data[z][x] !== '') {
            Logger.log('data[z][x] = '+data[z][x]+' and asking to CONTINUE');
            choices.push(item.createChoice(data[z][x]));
            for (var zz=0; zz<PageNamesValues.length; zz++) {
              // if a choice equals a Page name then go to that Page 
              if (data[z][x] == PageNamesValues[zz]){
                // I have problems converting the PageNames[x] variable to the correct PageNavigationType
                Logger.log('We found option "'+data[z][x]+'" matching Page Name "'+PageNamesValues[zz]+'"');
                item.createChoice(data[z][x], PageName);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        Logger.log('Set all choices to: '+choices);
        item.setChoices(choices);
      }
    } 
        for (var z=1; z<data.length; z++) {  
          if (data[z][x] !== '') {
            Logger.log('data[z][x] = '+data[z][x]+' and asking to CONTINUE');
            choicesPage1.push(itemPage1.createChoice(data[z][x]));
            for (var zz=0; zz<PageNamesValues.length; zz++) {
              // if a choice equals a Page name then go to that Page 
              if (data[z][x] == PageNamesValues[zz]){
                // I have problems converting the PageNames[x] variable to the correct PageNavigationType
                Logger.log('We found option "'+data[z][x]+'" matching Page Name "'+PageNamesValues[zz]+'"');
                itemPage1.createChoice(data[z][x], PageName);
            }
          }
        }
        Logger.log('Set all choicesPage1 to: '+choicesPage1);
        itemPage1.setChoices(choicesPage1);
  }
}
```

The log for the above code is:

> Winter
>
> [Winter]
>
> PageName is "PageBreakItem"
>
> data[z][x] = Skiing and asking to CONTINUE
>
> data[z][x] = Snowboarding and asking to CONTINUE
>
> data[z][x] = Snow and asking to CONTINUE
>
> data[z][x] = Rain and asking to CONTINUE
>
> data[z][x] = Snowman and asking to CONTINUE
>
> Set all choices to: Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice
>
> Banana
>
> [Winter, Banana]
>
> PageName is "PageBreakItem"
>
> data[z][x] = Yellow and asking to CONTINUE
>
> data[z][x] = Summer and asking to CONTINUE
>
> data[z][x] = Vitamin C and asking to CONTINUE
>
> data[z][x] = Fat free and asking to CONTINUE
>
> Set all choices to: Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice
>
> Apple
>
> [Winter, Banana, Apple]
>
> PageName is "PageBreakItem"
>
> data[z][x] = Vitamin C and asking to CONTINUE
>
> data[z][x] = Tree and asking to CONTINUE
>
> data[z][x] = Red and asking to CONTINUE
>
> data[z][x] = Green and asking to CONTINUE
>
> data[z][x] = Winter and asking to CONTINUE
>
> We found option "Winter" matching Page Name "Winter"
>
> Set all choices to: Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice
>
> data[z][x] = Apple and asking to CONTINUE
>
> We found option "Apple" matching Page Name "Apple"
>
> Set all choicesPage1 to: Choice
>
> data[z][x] = Banana and asking to CONTINUE
>
> We found option "Banana" matching Page Name "Banana"
>
> Set all choicesPage1 to: Choice,Choice
>
> data[z][x] = Orange and asking to CONTINUE
>
> Set all choicesPage1 to: Choice,Choice,Choice
>
> data[z][x] = Apricot and asking to CONTINUE
>
> Set all choicesPage1 to: Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice
>
> data[z][x] = Blackcurrant and asking to CONTINUE
>
> Set all choicesPage1 to: Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice
>
> data[z][x] = Blueberries and asking to CONTINUE
>
> Set all choicesPage1 to: Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice
>
> data[z][x] = Cherries and asking to CONTINUE
>
> Set all choicesPage1 to: Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice
>
> Set all choicesPage1 to: Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice
>
> Set all choicesPage1 to: Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice,Choice

Comment: Could you provide the logs?

Comment: I just added the logs on the main page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Page Navigation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/page-navigation-type) as mentioned in the documentation cannot have mixed navigation type, i.e. you cannot define certain choices to navigate to a certain page and leave the remaining blank. Even though you explicitly set them to submit earlier in the code, you have set it again for each choice you cannot find a match for. Like so:

```
for (var z=1; z<data.length; z++) {  
        if (data[z][x] !== '') {
          Logger.log('data[z][x] = '+data[z][x]);        
          var notFound = 1                              //whether page with name was found?
          for (var zz=0; zz<PageNames.length; zz++) {
            if (data[z][x] == PageNamesValues[zz]){     //When the page is found, since both arrays have the same index
              choices.push(item.createChoice(data[z][x], PageNames[zz]));  //you use same index to find set navigation
              notFound = 0
              Logger.log('We found option "'+data[z][x]+'" matching Page Name "'+PageNamesValues[zz]+'"');
              Logger.log('Choice navigation '+ choices[choices.length -1].getGotoPage().getTitle())
            } 
          }
          if (notFound == 1){
            // You cannot have certain choice navigate to a page and remaining not,
            // you will have to explicitly define that they submit if those choices are selected
           choices.push(item.createChoice(data[z][x],FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT));
          }
        }
      }
```

Secondly, think of pageBreakItem as another element in the form present at the start of each section. They direct the flow of the forms from one section to the other, they can be set to direct the flow to a different section with function `setGoToPage()`

```
// Set to navigate from the first page to the last pageBreakItem    
      if (x==0) {
         // Incorrect Line: PageNames[data[0].length-1].setGoToPage(PageNames[x])
         PageNames[PageNames.length-1].setGoToPage(PageNames[x])
      }
```

But at the same time can act as a forwarding address when used an argument in the `choices(pageBreakItem)` or `setGoToPage(pageBreakItem)` functions like so:

```
choices.push(item.createChoice(data[z][x], PageNames[zz]));
```

The way the program decide when to forward or when to act as the address is based on if the navigation to the page arrived via a ["normal linear progression through the form"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/page-break-item#getGoToPage())
. Or was directed to it explicitly via a function. 
Hope clears how to use page break item to direct the navigation of the page

Here is the final code:

```
function fruitForm() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Sheet = SS.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var data = Sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var form = FormApp.openById('FormID')
  .setDescription('Some description')
  .setConfirmationMessage('Have a fruity day:)')
  .setAllowResponseEdits(true)
  .setAcceptingResponses(true);
  Logger.log(form.getId())
  // Reset Multiple choice naviagtion , to enable forms to delete it. 
  var mulChoiceItems = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE)
  for (var i=0; i<mulChoiceItems.length; i++) {
    //Input dummy values to remove page navigation
    var item = mulChoiceItems[i].asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(["a","b"])
  } 

  //Delete Previous Form values
  var items = form.getItems();
  for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
      form.deleteItem(0);
  }

  //  asking user for name on the first page
  var text = form.addTextItem().setTitle('What is your name?').isRequired()
  var PageNames = [];
  var PageNamesValues = [];


  var temp =0;
  for (var x=data[0].length-1; x>=0; x--) {
    var choices = [];
    if (data[0][x] !== '') {
      temp = temp+1;     
      //Store pageBreakItem and their titles in the arrays
      //Note the arrays are filled in the same order for both pageBreakItem and their names
     //Thus preseving the relative index positions
      PageNames[x] = form.addPageBreakItem()
      .setTitle(data[0][x]);
      PageNamesValues[x] = PageNames[x].getTitle();
      Logger.log(PageNames);
      Logger.log(PageNamesValues);
      // I set all pages to SUBMIT except of the temp=1 (1st page)
      if (temp !== 1){
        PageNames[x].setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);
      }
      // Set to navigate from the first page to the last pageBreakItem    
      if (x==0) {
         // Incorrect Line: PageNames[data[0].length-1].setGoToPage(PageNames[x])
         PageNames[PageNames.length-1].setGoToPage(PageNames[x])
      }

      var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
      .setTitle(data[0][x])
      .showOtherOption(false)
      .setRequired(true);

      Logger.log(PageNames[x]);
      for (var z=1; z<data.length; z++) {  
        if (data[z][x] !== '') {
          Logger.log('data[z][x] = '+data[z][x]);        
          var notFound = 1                              //whether page with name was found?
          for (var zz=0; zz<PageNames.length; zz++) {
            if (data[z][x] == PageNamesValues[zz]){     //When the page is found, since both arrays have the same index
              choices.push(item.createChoice(data[z][x], PageNames[zz]));  //you use same index to find set navigation
              notFound = 0
              Logger.log('We found option "'+data[z][x]+'" matching Page Name "'+PageNamesValues[zz]+'"');
              Logger.log('Choice navigation '+ choices[choices.length -1].getGotoPage().getTitle())
            } 
          }
          if (notFound == 1){
            // Not you cannot have certain choice navigate to a page and remaining not,
            // you have to explicit define that they submit if those choices are selected
           choices.push(item.createChoice(data[z][x],FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT));
          }
        }
      }
      item.setChoices(choices);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @jack-brown. Your explanation was just perfect and to the point. Much appreciated.

Comment: The only change that I think it is needed on your resolution @jack-brown is on code

      if (x==0) {
         PageNames[data[0].length-1].setGoToPage(PageNames[x])
      }

it should be changed to code below, as data[0].length-1 contains more entries than the pages in this context. 

      if (x==0) {
         PageNames[PageNames.length-1].setGoToPage(PageNames[x])
      }

Comment: Good catch @senedot!